# Get package timeout with Docker - "golang.org/x/net/context/ctxhttp"

Tags: go, docker

I try to import this [package](https://github.com/olivere/elastic) using the go [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/).

From the docs of the package, the command to run is:

```
 go get gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v3
```

Works, fair enough.

I need to do the same with the docker image:

```
docker run -v $PWD:/temp -w /temp -e GOPATH=$PWD -e GOBIN=$PWD/bin golang:latest go get gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v3
```

But I got the following error:

> package golang.org/x/net/context: unrecognized import path
>   "golang.org/x/net/context" (https fetch: Get
>   https://golang.org/x/net/context?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup golang.org
>   on 192.168.65.1:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:46904->192.168.65.1:53: i/o
>   timeout)
>
> package golang.org/x/net/context/ctxhttp: unrecognized import
>   path "golang.org/x/net/context/ctxhttp" (https fetch: Get
>   https://golang.org/x/net/context/ctxhttp?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup
>   golang.org on 192.168.65.1:53: read udp
>   172.17.0.2:44687->192.168.65.1:53: i/o timeout)

Why is that?

Comment: Looks like you can't connect to golang.org, can you try running `curl https://golang.org` ?

Comment: I can. Both inside and outside the container.

Comment: DNS doesn't seem to be working on `192.168.65.1:53`.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker. Sometimes it does. I believe this is an error from the GO internal code.

Comment: You need golang 1.7 to get `net/context`.

Comment: @nouney It is unfortunately not the solution.

Comment: If DNS sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, that sounds like a DNS or network configuration issue, not a Go issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who will be looking at this question, I managed to find a solution. 
My `GOPATH` and `GOBIN` have been wrongly set. I should have used the go directory *inside* the docker container. 
The command then becomes:

```
docker run --rm -v $PWD:/t -w/t -e GOPATH=/t -e GOBIN=/t/bin golang:latest go get -v gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v3
```

For some reasons, it solved the DNS issue. I still don't understand why, but if I stumble on an explanation, I'll update here.